# Hosting images when deployed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, hosting, cloudinary

I'm beginner and using MERN. I've successfully deployed frontend and backend separately on render for testing purposes and when a user signs up they can choose a profile picture, now on localhost this works fine and it successfully adds to mongodb and shows in the web application. However when deployed I get an error that I can't 'GET' the image from the specific path.

Now I'm trying to workout with this is the case but could someone explain in ELI5 terms? Also would I need to host my images such as cloudinary? Thank you.

Tried to upload images when deployed but not being fetched.

Comment: How are the images managed in localhost? Where are you uploading them?

Comment: I've been uploading them into a public images folder using multer, basically I want to allow the user to upload images themselves and display in the web app, the mongodb is fine as it shows the uploaded image file name, I tried axios to my images folder on render but I guess it doesn't allow that as it won't GET the folder, would I need something like cloudinary for this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using `cloudinary` or an `S3 bucket` to store images in production.

1. First of all, call your `/upload` api route
2. Generate a `uuid` + `.extension (png or jpg)`
3. Upload this key as the name with your image file to `cloudinary` (for exemple)
4. Then save this key into your database to be able to access it later on.

If you consider using an `S3 bucket`, you should always configure a `CDN` between your client and your bucket to avoid billing’s surprises

Comment: Okay thank you for this, I will follow these steps and see how things get on... Is this fairly straight forward? As I have never done this I've only uploaded images locally.

Comment: `cloudinary` is very well documented and offer you a lot of options to resize images on the client size and much more. If it helped, consider mark your question as answered and don’t hesitate to ask for help

Comment: It may be recommended to check your app settings in Render (i.e., ensure to configure the “Root Directory” option accordingly - [see this documentation](https://community.render.com/t/deployment-fails-immediately-file-not-found/6648)). And in case you consider using Cloudinary for your asset management, you may take a look at the  Multer-Storage-Cloudinary which is a third-party application ([see this documentation](https://medium.com/@joeeasy_/uploading-images-to-cloudinary-using-multer-and-expressjs-f0b9a4e14c54))